# How to copy a file in PowerShell while it is in use?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, powershell, remote-access, copy

I need to copy a log file from a remote windows 2012 server. The log file will be written to constantly by our application. I know how to copy a remote file using `Copy-Item` Cmdlet. But I get error saying that `cannot access the file, because it is being used by another process`. 
Is there any way to get the file across even it is being used. Currently I RDC into the machine and copy it. I run analysis on log hourly which is scripted already, just this log file obtaining process is manual.

Comment: Try using robocopy?  I know it isn't native powershell, but generally that copies in-use files just fine.

Comment: If using robocopy (as @Zoredache wisely suggests) in automation with error handling, pay attention to the exit codes. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41306657/how-do-i-clear-error-and-lastexitcode-set-by-an-external-cmdlet-or-executable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS @Zoredache and @Matthew Wetmore suggested, I have tried `Robocopy`.

I have created a new drive using `New-PSDrive` to map the remote folder and used `Robocopy` to copy the desired log file while it's being written:

```
New-PSDrive -Name Logs -Root \\Svr01\d$\data -PSProvider Filesystem -Credentiaal $cred
Set-Location Logs:
robocopy .\logfiles\ ~\desktop\ service1.log /E
```

This copied over the `service1.log1` file from remote server `Svr01` to my local desktop.

Thanks to both @Zoredache and @Matthew Wetmore

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to use a pure powershell solution and this is what I came up with:

```
function Copy-Logs {
  [CmdletBinding()]
  param(
    [pscredential]$Credentials,
    $SourceDir,
    $SourceComputers
  )
  $SourceComputers `
  | ForEach-Object {
    $hostname = $_;
    "processing host: " + $hostname | Write-Verbose
    mkdir $hostname -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Out-Null
    $pssession = New-PSSession -Credential $Credentials -ComputerName $hostname;
    $fileInfos = Invoke-Command `
      -Session $pssession `
      -ScriptBlock { Get-ChildItem $args } `
      -ArgumentList $SourceDir
    $fileInfos `
    | ForEach-Object {
      $fileInfo = $_;
      $destFile = "$($hostname)/$($fileInfo.Name)"
      "copying file: $($fileInfo.FullName) to $($destFile)" | Write-Verbose
      Invoke-Command `
        -Session $pssession `
        -ScriptBlock { Get-Content $args; } `
        -ArgumentList $fileInfo.Fullname `
        > $destFile
    }
  }
}
```

It uses Get-Content to stream the file content from one host to the local machine